# Extract part of querystring using visual basic

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a querystring:

```
...default.aspx?date=May%202012
```

I want to get `may` and `2012` separately from that using:

```
Request.querystring("date")
```

....something similar for each.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx):

```
Dim dateParam = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("date"))
Dim dateParts = dateParam.Split(" "c)
Dim month = dateParts(0)
Dim year = dateParts(1)
```

C#

```
var dateParam = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["date"]);
var dateParts = dateParam.Split(' ');
var month = dateParts[0];
var year = dateParts[1];
```

**Edit**: As @Servy has commented `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` is redundant above since [`Request.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) decodes it implicitely, but it doesn't hurt ;-)

Comment: @Servy from question: `I want to get may and 2012 separately`

Comment: `Request.QueryString` already does a UrlDecode, it shouldn't be decoded again.

Comment: @Servy it is not related with url encoding/decoding. `date` parameter contains `May 2012` (in decoded form). So you have to split it to get the `May` and `2012`  separately.

Comment: @Servy: Edited my answer. I assume that OP just didn't know how to split both parts.

Comment: I got the above example to work with HttpUtility.UrlDecode, but am curious as to how I would split the querystring without it?

Comment: @mlg74:`Request.QueryString("date")` already decodes it, therfor you can split result as shown above.